# How do I only allow a user enter [1-9]-[some characters] into the textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a requirement that I have to allow the digits between 1-10000 and then"-" and then lastly some characters. can any one help me?

Comment: Why don't you keep 2 textboxes for that ?

Comment: what u have tried so far ?

Comment: trying this one http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/L3WxQ/

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
/^([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|10000)-[a-zA-Z]+$/
```